# how to convert mysql subquery in yii CDbCriteria?

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2

how to convert mysql subquery to yii CDbCriteria 
table list:
1) user_group
2) user_group_data
3) user_group_data_revision

```
select * from (
         select
         ugd.group_id as group_id,
         ug.user_id as user_id,
         ugd.id as group_data_id,
         ugd.group_name as group_name, 
         ugd.group_description as group_description,
         ugd.email as group_admin_email,
         ugd.image as group_image,
         ugd.group_type as group_type,
         ugd.request_type as group_request_type,
         ugdr.revision_version as revision_version,
         ugdr.admin_approve as revision_approve_status,
         ugdr.publish as revision_publish,
         ugdr.created_at as revision_created_at
         from user_group_data_revision ugdr
         left join user_group_data ugd on ugdr.group_data_id = ugd.id
         left join user_group ug on ugdr.group_id = ug.id
         order by `revision_version` desc
        ) rgd group by rgd.group_id
```

Comment: Please focus on my subquery not only relation.

Answer (score 4):

Here a small example(if I correctly understood structure/relations):

```
//Model UserGroupDataRevision
class UserGroupDataRevision extends CActiveRecord 
{
     public function relations()
     {
        return array(
            'userGroup' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'UserGroup', 'group_id'),
            'userGroupData' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'UserGroupData', 'group_data_id'),
        );
     }
     //....
}

//model UserGroup
class UserGroup extends CActiveRecord {...}
//model UserGroupData
class UserGroupData extends CActiveRecord {...}
```

Criteria:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 'ugdr.revision_version'; // other fields
$criteria->alias = 'ugdr';
$criteria->with = array(
        'userGroup' => array(
        'alias' => 'ug',
        'together' => true,
        'select' => array('ug.user_id'), // other fields
    ),
    'userGroupData' => array(
        'alias'=> 'ugd',
        'together' => true,
        'select'=>array('ugd.group_id, ugd.group_name'), // other fields
    ),
);
$criteria->group = 'rgd.group_id';
$criteria->order = 'rgd.group_id'; // or something else
```

Data checking:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('UserGroupDataRevision', array(
      'criteria' => $criteria,
   )
);
var_dump($dataProvider->getData());
die();
```

Comment: Please focus on my subquery not only relation. i have to not apply group & order at a time.

Comment: @BharatChauhan not understand. Could you more explain your problem? Do you check data from sql query and from DataProvider?

Comment: @BharatChauhan some dummy data in the table with expected output would have been helpful.