# Select data from relations table in yii

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, relational-database

I have some problem with fetch data from table wich have relations.
I 3 tables: Good,Shop_attr_value, and Shop_good_attr_val.Table     Shop_attr_value has a value of properties(like size of memory, or type of processor), and Shop_good_attr_val has a foreign key to table Good and
Shop_attr_value(they point what of type of memory has good).So I need fetch Good and her type of processor. I tried this:

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->join = 'JOIN tbl_shop_attr_value';
    $criteria->with = 'goodAttrVals';
    $criteria->select='t.name,tbl_shop_attr_value.value';
    $criteria->addCondition('t.id = goodAttrVals.good_id AND ON tbl_shop_attr_value.id = goodAttrVals.attr_value_id');
```

But I got error that said

> uknown column tbl_shop_attr_value.value

Good relations:

```
   public function relations()
{

    return array(

        'idGood' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'GoodsColor', 'id_good'),
        'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Category', 'category_id'),
        'brand' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Brand', 'brand_id'),
        'goodAttrVals' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'GoodAttrVal', 'good_id'),
        'goodImages' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'GoodImage', 'good_id'),
        'reviews' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Review', 'good_id', 'condition'=>'reviews.status=:status', 'params'=>array('status'=>Review::STATUS_ACTIVE), 'order'=>'reviews.id DESC'),
    );
}
```

How I can fetch this data?

Comment: It is because tbl_shop_attr_value.value not exist in table with alias 't'. You need use $criteria->with like array. Here a small example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759875/how-to-convert-mysql-subquery-in-yii-cdbcriteria/31760987#31760987

Comment: Thank for your replay. I tried this: `$criteria->with = array('goodAttrVals'=>array(
            'alias'=>'p',
            'select'=>'attrValue.value',
            'condition'=>'p.attr_value_id = attrValue.id',
            'together' => true,
        ));
        $criteria->select='t.name';
        $criteria->addCondition('t.id = goodAttrVals.good_id');` But I again got error: _uknown column goodAttrVals.good_id_

Comment: change t.id = goodAttrVals.good_id  TO t.id = p.good_id

Answer (score 0):

I juust add `$criteria->with = array('goodAttrVals', 'goodAttrVals.attrValue');` Where goodAttrVals and attrValue is name relations