# Create pagination in yii framework

Tags: php, gridview, yii, pagination

I want to create pagination on my page without grid-view or model.
This is my controller code:-

```
        $providers = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
        $count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();

        $dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
           'totalItemCount' => $count,
           'pagination' => array(
               'pageSize' => 10,
           ),
        ));
```

and my view code is:-

```
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
           'id'=>'students-grid',
           'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider, 
        )); ?>
```

But when I run this its show error message

```
    "Array to string conversion"
```

and 2nd option which I had try that is :-

```
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
        $pages = new CPagination($count);

        // results per page
        $pages->pageSize=10;
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

        //$models=Article::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

But I don't know how to use this code because i have no model in this time.On the place of model what I can use?

Comment: Can you show variable **$query**?

Comment: Why you use 2 the same queries? Maybe this way more correct? `$providers = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll(); $count = count($providers); `

Comment: @DanilaGanchar  please check this in I had paste query here http://pastebin.com/vcqNMEZw

Comment: And now your `$count` is array, but not integer. `totalItemCount` must be integer. [Public Properties of CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider)

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Now I am using $count=count(Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll()); and this is integer value, but problem  is still...

Comment: Check this hope this help <br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616183/yii2-custom-paginaion-for-union-query/36616271#36616271

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Hope this help you.

```
//controller
$count = Yii::app()
   ->db //your count of records
   ->createCommand('
      select COUNT(*) AS total
        from providers p 
        left join providers_facilities_services fs on fs.provider_guid = p.provider_guid 
        left join lkup_facilitytypes l on l.lkup_facilitytype_id = fs.lkuptype_id and fs.type='F' left join providers_media m on m.provider_guid = p.provider_guid 
        left join providers_contacts as comp on comp.provider_guid= p.provider_guid where p.provider_class='F' and comp.contact_type='U' and fs.type='F' and p.deleted = 'N' and fs.lkuptype_id =5 HAVING distance <= 20000
   ')
   ->queryColumn();

$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
    'totalItemCount' => $count[0],
    'pagination' => array(
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ),
));

//view
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
       'id' => 'students-grid',
       'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider, 
)); ?>
```

Comment: First what I see: You have not `'id' => 'students-grid'` in your example. Second. Try to check your `$query`. Set to `totalItemCount` test value(200 for example). `$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
    'totalItemCount' => 200,
    'pagination' => array(
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ),
));`. If problem will be exists then problem in your sql.

Comment: when I am using  this code :- $providers = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
   $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
   $count = count(Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll());
   $pages=new CPagination($count);
   $pages->pageSize=10;
   $pages->applyLimit($criteria);
   $providerreports = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll($criteria); its show all records on page but when I use  "$providerreports=ProviderReport::model()->findAll($criteria);" this line its show 10 results but I have no models  so please tell me what is the mistake on above code

Comment: It is because in first example you use `Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll($criteria)`, but in second: `ProviderReport::model()->findAll($criteria)`. Try to convert your sql to `CDbCriteria`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759875/how-to-convert-mysql-subquery-in-yii-cdbcriteria/31760987#31760987) example. It will be work with `CPagination + ProviderReport::model()->findAll($criteria)`.

Comment: And update you question. Now there is no error **Array to string conversion**.

Comment: But I have no model , I want to use this line Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll($criteria) on place of  this ProviderReport::model()->findAll($criteria)

Comment: Please update your question. Do you have any error? What model you do not have? What is the question? 50% of answer exists in correct question ;)

Comment: when I use this Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll($criteria) then its show all result on first page like if I have 200 records then its show 200 records on 1st page, but according to my code its should show only 10 results on first page right and I can't use this model  ProviderReport::model()->findAll($criteria), I have result on this line Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll($criteria)

Comment: convert your sql to CDbCriteria and update the question, as I asked above.

Comment: Oooh, come on... I asked above... Conver your `select p.provider_id,p.provider_guid, p.provider_name etc...` to CDbCriteria. Your criteria is not have a conditions. Therefore shows 200 records. And as I asked above. Update your question. Add sql + your problem, remove error **Array to string conversion**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87135/discussion-between-renu-thakur-and-danila-ganchar).