# Yii2 pagination returns last page when requesting an invalid page

Tags: php, yii2

I am using ActiveDataProvider to return paginated results which mostly works fine. But when if there are (for example) 5 pages and the request asks for any pages above 5, the result set is page 5 when I would expect no records at all.

Is this expected behaviour? If not what can I try to fix it?

Example code:

```
return new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
       'query' => $query,
       'pagination' => [
           'pageSize' => $perPage,
       ],
]);
```

Comment: unclear what are you asking?

Comment: please check following URL:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987006/create-pagination-in-yii-framework/31989183#31989183

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: this is the expected behavior.

If you're interested, `Pagination` class has this [`validatePage`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html#$validatePage-detail) attribute that by default is `true`. If page validation is on, then you'll get page set to last page if it's greater than that.

You can set this parameter to `false`, and then most likely you'll get zero results in your grid.